# importing (appending) materials from File

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, append

I am using Blender 2.8 and cycles render I wanted to download a few materials from websites like http://matrep.parastudios.de/ when I download the files I follow what others have said to do. select file-append and then select the blender file and select the materials in the material folder in that blender file. when I do this I select the blender files but then there is nothing there is no other folders..what I am doing wrong, is there a plugin for 2.8 that helps with stuff like this there is the material library addon you can load by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downloaded files from that old site do not appear to be blend files, which is why appending does not work.

While there have been a few different material library addons, there are two options that are currently working (and included) with 2.80. The first addon is listed as [Material Library](https://sites.google.com/site/aleonserra/home/scripts/matlib-vx) and was previously called "matlib vx", the other is a new addon called [BlenderKit](https://www.blenderkit.com) which provides a much wider library of resources that includes models, scenes and brushes.